# How to get the expectation of a parameter θ from a joint distribution p(θ,D) in the context of Bayesian learning?

Tags: probability, statistics, machine-learning, bayesian

Page 74 in [pattern recognition and machine learning (free)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2006/01/Bishop-Pattern-Recognition-and-Machine-Learning-2006.pdf) says

> ... we see that as the number of observations increases, so the
>   posterior distribution becomes more sharply peaked ...
>   we can take a frequentist view of Bayesian learning and show
>   that, on average, such a property does indeed hold. Consider a general Bayesian
>   inference problem for a parameter θ for which we have observed a data set D, described by the joint distribution p(θ,D). The following result says that the posterior mean of θ, averaged over the distribution generating the data,
>   is equal to the prior mean of θ.

[image]

Where does equation 2.21 come from? Why is left side equal to right side?

Comment: (2.21) looks like the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation)

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a useful formula in calculating expectations.

$$\mathbb{E}_\theta[\theta]=\int_{\Theta}{\theta f_\Theta(\theta)d\theta}=\int_{\Theta}{\theta\left[\int_{\mathcal{D}}{f_{\Theta,\mathcal{D}}(\theta,x)dx}\right]d\theta}$$

$$=\int_{\mathcal{D}}{\left[\int_\Theta{\theta f_{\Theta,\mathcal{D}}(\theta,x)d\theta}\right]dx}=\int_{\mathcal{D}}{\mathbb{E}_\theta[\theta\mid\mathcal{D}]dx}=\mathbb{E}_\mathcal{D}[\mathbb{E}_\theta[\theta\mid\mathcal{D}]].$$

The integrals may not be so strict, but I think the ideas are the same.

Comment: It seems that you are using $f_\Theta(\theta)$ to denote the term that is denoted by $p(\theta)$ in equation 2.22, right?

Comment: Yes. Sorry I should have checked it before I wrote the answer. But I hope you could get the point. It is simply a permutation of integration. For more references, you can see a similar argument on P164, Theorem 4.4.3 of *Statistical Inference* by George Casella and Roger L. Berger.